# Problem in indexing an element of an Account's Vec

Tags: solana-program

I have the following account.

```
#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct UserGame {
    pub hand: Vec<Hand>,
}

#[derive(Clone, AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize)]
pub struct Hand {
    pub hand_stated: bool,
    pub bet: i32,
    pub cards: Vec<i8>,
}
```

Now the problem I have is when trying to index a  out of the UserGame Vec, the compiler references the object as this.

```
    let hand: <i8 as SliceIndex<[Hand]>>::Output = *user_game.hand.get(index_hand).unwrap();
```

I don't understand how can I get the Hand object, my question might be inutile, but Im new to Rust.

Comment: Can you give some more information about the error? You should be able to get it working simply with: `let hand = user_game.hand.get(index_hand).unwrap();`